# Combining These MySQL Queries and SUM data with one Query

Tags: mysql

I need to combine these two queries and get records using the single mySQL query.

Here are my queries

```
select DATE_FORMAT(campaign_date, '%Y-%m' ) AS month
     , sum(sms) 
  from table1 
 group 
    by month
```

it returns me, sum of all months e.g

```
 2019-05 5400
 2019-06 3200
 2019-07 11505
 etc
```

I have another query which gets data in same format but from a different table.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(trans_date, '%Y-%m' ) AS month
     , sum(camp_sms) 
  from table2 
 group 
    by month

2019-05  3500
2019-06  7256 
2019-07 35465
etc
```

is it possible to combine these two query and get data same like this below:

```
Date sum(sms) sum(camp_sms)
2019-05  5400  3500
2019-06  3200  7256
2019-07 11505 35465
```

I have done this using PHP loops & array and to get the same output, but i want to do it using mySQL.

Comment: Yes, you can write procedures for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `join`

```
select t1.month, t1.total, t2.total from (
    select DATE_FORMAT(campaign_date, '%Y-%m' ) AS month, sum(sms) total from table1 group by month
) t1
join (
    select DATE_FORMAT(trans_date, '%Y-%m' ) AS month, sum(camp_sms) from table2 group by month
) t2 on t1.month = t2.month
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to skip any data from table1, then you should `LEFT JOIN` similarly you can use other joins according to your requirements.